# StringLengthAttribute and Localized text

Tags: c#, .net, data-annotations

The following code was grabbed from MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.stringlengthattribute.aspx

```
[MetadataType(typeof(ProductMetadata))]
public partial class Product
{

}

public class ProductMetadata
{

    [ScaffoldColumn(true)]
    [StringLength(4, ErrorMessage = "The ThumbnailPhotoFileName value cannot exceed 4 characters. ")]
    public object ThumbnailPhotoFileName;

}
```

How can I apply localize text (ex: from a Resource file) to the error message?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`ValidationAttribute.ErrorMessageResourceType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.errormessageresourcetype.aspx) property to refer to your resource file, and the [`ValidationAttribute.ErrorMessageResourceName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationattribute.errormessageresourcename.aspx) property to refer to the name of the string within that resource file. For example:

```
[StringLength(4, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(YourResourceFileHere), ErrorMessageResourceName = "NameOfStringInResourceFile")]
```

You can also check out [this blog post](http://publicityson.blogspot.com/2010/07/localizing-validation-using.html) if you need more examples.